# Grouping and get FirstOrDefault LINQ.js

Tags: jquery, linq.js

i am trying to use Linq.Js in one of my project.The problem is that i have to apply grouping and then use sum on some columns and pick first of some columns.
e.g.

```
var list = [
           { a: 2, b: 4, c: 1 },
           { a: 2, b: 3, c: 7 },
           { a: 2, b: 3, c: 3 },
           { a: 4, b: 7, c: 5 },
           { a: 7, b: 3, c: 2 },
           { a: 4, b: 1, c: 5 }];
```

result will be
group on a, sum of b and take first of c

```
a:2,b:10,c:1
a:7,b:3,c:2
a:4,b:1,c:5
```

Till now i have tried,

```
var aggregatedObject = Enumerable.From(claimForCalculation)
               .GroupBy("$.a", null,
                 function (key, g) {
                     var result = {
                         groupedKey: key,
                         chargedQty: g.Sum("$.b"),
                         chargedRate: g.FirstOrDefault("$.c"),
                     }
                     return result;
                 }, function (x) {  return x }).ToArray();
```

But it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you shouldn't be passing anything into the `FirstOrDefault()` method.  The parameter there is the predicate used to select the first item, it's not a selector.  Just take the first of the group and get the `c` property.

You could write your query like this:

```
var query = Enumerable.From(list)
    .GroupBy("$.a", null, "{ a: $, b: $$.Sum('$.b'), c: $$.First().c }")
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: Hey @jeff ,its works. One more question, if i want to do some calculation after we perform grouping can we do in same query. e.g. we got above output a:2,b:10,c:1
a:7,b:3,c:2
a:4,b:2,c:5. Now for each line item if we want to check if c > 3 then perform C * b as d else it will be c. After logic output will be .. a:2,b:10,c:1,d:1
a:7,b:3,c:2,d:2
a:4,b:2,c:5:d:10